# Can't draw in UIImage without changing contentMode

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift3, uiimage

I'm currently building a photo filter in Swift 3.0 that lets the user pixellate parts of images with panning.

To do this, I first pixellate the image, put it in an UIImageView that I display ; I then display the original image on top and use a panGestureRecognizer linked to an "erase" function that erases parts of the top image, letting the user see the pixellated version behind.

**My problem**

Everything is working properly here, the only problem I have is that, when pan begins, the top image is resized (it actually looks like its contentMode is switching to scaleAspectFit instead of scaleAspectFill).

**My code**

```
func eraseBetween(fromPoint: CGPoint, currentPoint: CGPoint, imageView: UIImageView) {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: imageView.frame.width , height: imageView.frame.height ), false, 0.0)

    imageView.image?.draw(in: imageView.bounds)

    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.move(to: fromPoint)
    path.addLine(to: currentPoint)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.setShouldAntialias(true)
    context.setLineCap(lineType)
    context.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
    context.setBlendMode(.clear)
    context.addPath(path)
    context.strokePath()

    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

**What it looks like**

[Before pan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al0RP.jpg)

[After pan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrq7j.jpg)

**What I tried so far**

I tried to play with the options of UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions : no result

I tried to redefine contentMode inside my eraseBetween function : no result

And for now I have no idea left!

**Question**

Is anyone kind enough to help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Please take a moment to review our [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).